# How can I create a dual function button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a application which has a start button(with a play image). once the start button is clicked the next click it should act like a pause button (also a change in button image). How can we implement both this function with image changing one for play and another for pause with the same button?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 4):

This is how i'd handle it

In your viewController definition define a bool

```
BOOL playing;
```

then in the button action you should do something like

```
-(IBAction)playPauseButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    if (playing)
    {
         [self pauseButtonClicked];
    }
    else
    {
         [self playButtonClicked];
    }

    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    playing = !playing;
    [theButton setImage:playing ? @"pauseImage.png":@"playImage.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)pauseButtonClicked
{
    // Handle pausing
}
-(void)playButtonClicked
{
    // Handle starting to play
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

 UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[button setImage:pauseImage forState:state];
//Do things
}
```

Comment: sory .my question is how can we implement both this function with image changing one for play and another for pause  with the  same button?

Comment: keep a bool as global.Set it to one in the begining.set it it to zero when the button is clicked and so. each time the button is clicked, check whether the bool is set or not.If set the button is on and put the image for on and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

The global **BOOL** is not necessary. Simply set an image for `UIControlStateSelected` (i.e. *Play*) and another for `UIControlStateNormal` (i.e. *pause*) and in your action method:

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = sender;
        button.selected = !button.selected;
        if (button.selected)
            // Play
        else //Pause
    }
```

Comment: Nice one, but personally, i don't like directly relying on properties of user interface/view objects to figure out the state of the program. If i didn't want to keep the state in a variable, i'd use a a bool @property and check for the button "selected" property in the getter, just to be able to change the condition easily, because i easily see the OP's app depending on the playing/not playing state in other places in the program as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)playClicked:(id)sender{

UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]]) {
    [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

else {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

All the best.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't checking for equality like that between two images be CPU heavy? Is it comparing some sort of hash or their path or something?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a boolean in the click method that keeps track if it is playing already or not. If it is not playing start it and set the image to the pause image, if it is playing then when its pressed again do whatever you need it to do, i.e. pause and change image.

This loop would be in your click method:

```
if(playing) {
    //if the button is pressed and its already playing, pause or do whatever here
    [button setImage:startImage forState:normal];
    playing = NO;
} else {
    [button setImage:pauseImage forState:normal];
    playing = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Here is my code. Have a look.

    @IBAction func playAndPauseButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.scene!.paused = true

            if (playAndPauseButton.currentImage == UIImage(named: "play.png"))
            {
                playAndPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            else
            {
                playAndPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                skView.scene!.paused = false
            }

        }

Note: I used this in a sample game where I have button which pause and play the game scene.
```